# Aggregate query with multiple distinct counts as separate columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm having a bit of trouble getting a query to output what I want.

Here's a scenario. I'm looking to get the distinct count of employees by state/zip by 'Category'. Some example data is below.

[image: Example data and desired output]

Now I'm not looking to pivot the data. The count lines will be dynamically added in the future. This is the format that I'm aiming for. I'm aware that the "count" lines are incorrect syntax but I'm just trying to express what my goal is.

```
SELECT 
  State
  , Zip
  , count(distinct EmployeeID where category = 'Red') RedCount
  , sum(case when category='Red' then 1 else 0 end) as RedCountAlternateAttempt
  , count(distinct EmployeeID where category = 'Blue') BlueCount

group by State,Zip
```

Thanks for any guidance.

Comment: What about orange?

Comment: @SalmanA I plan on adding each aggregation dynamically based on input - in this case I'm demonstrating that Orange was not desired so I dont want it included in the  results

Answer (score 3):

The correct syntax uses `case`:

```
selecct State, Zip,
       count(distinct case when category = 'Red' then EmployeeID end) as RedCount,
       sum(case when category = 'Red' then 1 else 0 end) as RedCountAlternateAttempt,
       count(distinct case when category = 'Blue' then EmployeeID end) BlueCount
group by State, Zip;
```

Comment: That's what I was leaning towards, but that wouldn't get the distinct employee counts right?

Comment: This one would give '3' for the red count in the RedCountAlternateAttempt column for zip 11111. I suppose I could clean up duplicates in a cte and query that, but I was seeking a solution that would take the distinct count/sum in one clause

Comment: @Scotch . . . But there is "2" in the `RedCount`.  That seems to do what you want.